# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1901-01-01 00:00:00"

Tags: java, linux, simpledateformat, java.util.date

This piece of code works correctly in Windows, but in Linux throws a java.text.ParseException:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", new Locale("es", "ES"));
df.setLenient(false);
Date date = df.parse("1901-01-01 00:00:00");
System.out.println(date);
```

Windows output:

```
Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 1901
```

Linux output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:340)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1901-01-01 00:00:00"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
        ...
```

If a remove the `df.setLenient(false)` line, the Windows output is the same, and  the Linux exception disappears, however the Linux output seems to be incorrect:

```
Tue Jan 01 00:14:44 CET 1901
```

Does somebody know what is going on?

Thanks

Configuration:
Windows: Win7 + jdk1.7.0_71
Linux: Ubuntu + jdk1.7.0_60

EDIT: As anolsi said is a Daylight Saving problem. With the date "2015-03-29 02:00:01" the parse exception is thrown, in Windows and Linux, because this date doesn't exist in Madrid (the time was changed from 2:00AM to 3:00AM in Madrid that day). So the correct behaviour is the Linux one. The Windows JDK should throw the exception.

Comment: Is it Oracle or OpenJDK on Linux? Shouldn't make a difference but just in case.

Comment: Should not be an issue. Works fine for me.

Comment: Could be a problem that has been fixed between u60 and u71. Try updating the JDK.

Comment: Does Java use any timezone/locale databases from the host OS (or all rolled into the JDK)? If it does, could also be an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Interesting. I just ran your code in my Linux machine and it works!

Comment: Have you understood my explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be related with the Locale/Timezone definition you are using.

As you can check under http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/spain/madrid?year=1901 that specific time didn't exists on that Timezone, because the DST (Daylight Saving Time). This should be causing the inconsistency.

If you try instead `1901-02-01 00:00:00`, for instance, it should work fine.

EDIT1: Example that allow changing and controlling the Timezone.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainClass
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", new Locale("es", "ES"));
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
        df.setLenient(false);
        Date date = df.parse("1901-01-01 00:00:00");
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

EDIT2: Please take a look on the good article regarding timezones and offsets: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info

Comment: So the Linux behaviour is actually the correct one?

Comment: I am not satisfied with this, I tried the same code in my local linux machine and it works. How do you explain that?

Comment: Because your uimezone under your Linux shouldn't be using the Madrid Timezone. I'm not sure if the local will also set the Timezone.

Comment: @Thilo It will depends, how it is really assuming the Timezone. The problem can be there. But in fact that specific time didn't existed (considering Spain). That is a common problem about DST. Values that look a correct date, but that didn't represent any known moment of time.

Comment: So to make this reproducible across systems, one could specify an explicit timezone (the one for Madrid) somewhere?

Comment: I know to options to assure that: use the option `-Duser.timezone=Europe/Madrid` on java run, the other is to start the date formatter with: `df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));`. Check the new example above.